# Azure Devops Publish Test Result Task - Test Tab ScreenShot

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I want to take a screenshot of publish test result task - test tabs. 
Is there any way to do that?

And when i take the screenshot i will add it an email and send it.
Example is below.

Note: I dont use visualstudio. Just making an existing repo's pipeline.

AzureDevops Publish Test Result

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zp4vv.png)

Answer (score 0):

There is no direct way to do it with Azure devops, but you can use the extension
[Publish Test Result Screenshot](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Genetec.publish-test-result-screenshot)